# USB ports and other peripheral devices on laptop sometimes don't work

Tags: drivers, usb, asus, peripherals

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus n551jm.

After one or several reboots, USB (and other peripheral devices) start working correctly.

How can I get them to work every time I boot?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for my problem is a bug in core (previous versions) for my laptop. Now I use 3.19.0-74 Kernel and don't have problems.

Comment: Would you add more info about your case, laptop model, which previous kernel versions have the issue? If you managed to file a bug report or found already existing one, please add its link.

Comment: Linux 3.13.0-87-generic

Comment: My laptop model is Asus n551jm. Linux core 3.13.0-87-generic working relatively stable, cause restarting of laptop (when USB's switched off) helps switch on USBs, but 3.13.0-86 and earliest versions worked with problems, usb don't work. I used 3.13.0-87 core, before updating to 3.19.0-74, with this core i don't have problems. Now use it as stable. I don't add bug report.

Comment: Excuse me Slb, I did notice before that you same person who asks (i wouldn't ask you for pc model). The question is closed, however, your last comment add important info, so could you [edit] the answer and add it there. It will more visible to other user looking for a fix/workaround of same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install this kernel. A link to such a resource (preferably on AskUbuntu or the Ubuntu Community Wiki) would be fine too. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: I don't install it manually, it was installed with updates. Somebody can find in internet how to install kernel.